# is there a portable way to get a pointer for struct with virtual table through a pointer to a member of it

Tags: c++

in my io completion ports implementation I was delivering notifications through a switch statement on an opcode in a struct inheriting from OVERLAPPED structure expecting that the OVERLAPPED base is at offset 0 from the derived one

later I used a virtual method in the derived struct instead of an opcode with a switch , this made the design easier and more clear . I was still thinking that the OVERLAPPED structure is at offset 0 so I simply used something like this to issue an io operation :

`WSASend(ns, &wsbuf, 1, &sent, 0, (LPWSAOVERLAPPED)(std::addressof(CTX)), nullptr);`

where `CTX` is a struct of type `BaseIoCtx` which is :

```
BaseIoCtx : public OVERLAPPED
{

    void *fd;

    virtual void HandleIocpPacket(io::iocp::CompletionResult& IocpPacket) = 0;

    virtual ~BaseIoCtx() = default;
};
```

and in casting back in the io loop I used this code :

```
// BaseIoCtx inherits from OVERLAPPED
// result is an OVERLAPPED_ENTRY
BaseIoCtx *ctx = reinterpret_cast<BaseIoCtx*>(result.lpOverlapped);
ctx->HandleIocpPacket(result); // the virtual function that delivers the notification
```

I thought this should work well , and it worked well for more than month !

yesterday after doing some tests I got a strange crash at this line :

`ctx->HandleIocpPacket(result); // the virtual function that delivers the notification`

the debugger was saying : `read access violation ... ctx-> was (nullptr, 0XFFFFFFFF, any strange address)`

however I seed ctx itself was at a valid address in the visual studio debugger and contained the correct transferred length in the OVERLAPPED base but the `__vfptr` was `nullptr` or a very strange address like 0xFFFFFFF or 0xCCCCCCCCC so I set a breakpoint on the line before submitting the io request and saw that the __vfptr was pointing to a valid `vtable` and contained the two virtual functions of `BaseIoCtx` , so I figured that during the io request some windows internal function wrote at the `__vfptr` and corrupted it .

I was wondering because I though the base structure was at the start of the derived not the `__vfptr` but after some experiments with offsetof I found that `__vfptr` was at offset 0 instead !

yet I then changed the `BaseIoCtx` into this :

```
struct BaseIoCtx : public IoContext
{

    OVERLAPPED ov = { 0 };

    static BaseIoCtx * from_ov_ptr(OVERLAPPED *ov_ptr) noexcept
    {
        constexpr std::size_t ov_offset = offsetof(BaseIoCtx, ov);
        return reinterpret_cast<BaseIoCtx*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ov_ptr) - ov_offset);
    }

    void *fd;

    virtual void HandleIocpPacket(io::iocp::CompletionResult& IocpPacket) = 0;

    virtual ~BaseIoCtx() = default;
};
```

and in the the submitting I used :

`WSASend(ns, &wsbuf, 1, &sent, 0, (LPWSAOVERLAPPED)(std::addressof(CTX.ov)), nullptr);`

then in the io loop I got back the structure as :

`BaseIoCtx * ctx = BaseIoCtx::from_ov_ptr(result.lpOverlapped);`

and it works well . now the questions are : how did the first implementation worked for long time on the same compiler ! and is the new one considered a portable way in c++ rather than a hack and if it is a hack is there a better one ?

Comment: Code that seems to work does not mean that it is the correct code. You most likely cause some undefined behavior somewhere, and undefined behavior means anything can happen even the expected result. Switching/Updating the compiler or altering the code can introduce a different memory layout, different code generation due to optimization, ... and this changes then could cause this undefined behavior to result into a crash, or wrong results.

Comment: From a quick read of the documentation it seems like if you pass a completion routine to WsaSend then you can use the `hEvent` parameter of `OVERLAPPED` for your own purposes, you could store your class pointer in there. I could be wrong

Comment: Having a `reinterpret_cast` especially something like `reinterpret_cast<BaseIoCtx*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ov_ptr) - ov_offset)` is always a good indication, that something is done wrong. But I'm not familiar with `WSASend` or `winsock2` in general, so I can't really tell why you want/have to solve it that way, and how it should be done correctly.

Comment: the overlapped structure is like a ctx data that is to be passed to callback and at the same time a place for the system to store the io operation data so I have to pass a pointer to an overlapped structure so that the system will store the information in it and then will post it back through iocp or apc , so to distinguish different operations and callers I have to store these information somewhere and be able to get them from the overlapped structure . It's a c api so no consideration for virtual functions that will fit better in c++

Comment: from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0545r0.html)  under 4.3 section : `In fact, some implementations (GCC 6.2, Clang 3.8, MSVC 19) do support offsetof with classes having virtual functions` and `For these reasons this proposal does not require support for classes with virtual functions and leaves them conditionally-supported. A future proposal could require such support if the need appears` . So it's really no a standard way but it works for these major compilers and may work for more

Comment: also at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) it is stated that : `If type is not a standard layout type, the behavior is undefined (until C++17)use of the offsetof macro is conditionally-supported (since C++17)` . so I can assume it should work with no harm as far as the compiler gives a support for it